# How do I check individual parts of a list?

Tags: python

If I have a list of random `int`s and then check each individual value of it being even or odd, how would I do that?

Comment: Show an example of how you want to use it at least.

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in list:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        print('even!')
    else:
        print('odd!')
```

What I'm doing here is using a for loop to go through the `list`. For each element in the list, `i` is assigned to be the current element, then I check if `i` is divisible by 2 (i.e. if `i` is even). If it is, I print that the element is even, and if not, then I print that the element is odd.

Comment: Can you also explain your code? This will help OP way more.